# ZF2 - RuntimeException: Module (ZfcUserDoctrineORM) could not be initialized

Tags: php, zend-framework2, runtime-error, composer-php

Just download the installer from the composer. This is what I have on my composer.json:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "zf-commons/zfc-user": "dev-master",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.3.*",
        "zendframework/zend-developer-tools":"dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module":"dev-master",
        "bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize": "1.4.*"
    }
```

Performed the commands php composer.php self-update and php install composer.phar, got success.

In my application.config have the following modules:

```
'modules' => array(
        'Base',
        'DoctrineModule',
        'DoctrineORMModule',
        'ZendDeveloperTools',
        'ZfcBase',
        'ZfcUser',
        'ZfcUserDoctrineORM',
        'ZendDeveloperTools',
        'BjyAuthorize',
        'Users',
        'Facebook'
      ),
```

The problem happens when I try to run my application: always returns the status 500 with the stack trace:

```
Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (ZfcUserDoctrineORM) could not be initialized.' in /home/triangulum/workspace-php/apegueme/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php:195
Stack trace:
#0 /home/triangulum/workspace-php/apegueme/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php(169): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModuleByName(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))
#1 /home/triangulum/workspace-php/apegueme/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php(96): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModule('ZfcUserDoctrine...')
#2 [internal function]: Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->onLoadModules(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))
#3 /home/triangulum/workspace-php/apegueme/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent))
#4 /home/triangulum/workspace-ph in /home/triangulum/workspace-php/apegueme/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php on line 195
```

Already remade this process a few times and always got the same result.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
I'm giving this maintenance code, and saw that the previous developer downloaded off the composer.